# Django didn't save data to postgre during test case executing

Tags: django, postgresql, unit-testing

I have webapp, which has a lot of big calculation logic. To stable it and spend less time to regress tests I decided to create some unit test cases on Django.
My purpose  - don't create new test DB (I use Postgre SQL, is important) for every testcases running and save DB with all test data after test cases finished. I need to have test data for analysis and search bugs.

I created custom TestRunner, which inherited on DiscoverRunner with change some parameters:
`keepdb = True debug_mode = True verbosity = 2`
This thing is work, I reuse one DB for all test-cases.

My problem is I don't see test data which created during test cases in my test DB. I had some failed testcases or all OK - nothing change.

Interesting facts for me:

1. During test cases I have some queries to DB about new test data and these queries returns right result.
2. During test cases I created new objects and sequences in DB are changed as if test data exists in DB.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing database and data in the database.

I would guess that the `keepdb` flag only keeps the database (schema etc.).

Some testcase remove the data at the end of the run, eg. [TransactionTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase)

> TestCase running on a database that does not support rollback (e.g. MySQL with the MyISAM storage engine), and all instances of TransactionTestCase, will roll back at the end of the test by deleting all data from the test database.

Comment: if it solved your issue you could accept the answer :-)